# $ 1+\mathsf{d}^\star(B) \le \mathsf{d}^\star(A\cup B)+\mathsf{d}^\star(B\cup C) $ with $A\cup B\cup C=\bf{N}^+$

Tags: real-analysis, number-theory, limsup-and-liminf

For each subset of positive integers $X\subseteq \bf N^+$ define the upper asymptotic density as
$$
\mathsf{d}^\star(X)=\limsup_{n\to \infty} \frac{|X\cap [1,n]|}{n}.
$$

**Problem:**  Let $A,B,C$ be a partition of the positive integers $\bf N^+$. Is it true that
$$
1+\mathsf{d}^\star(B) \le \mathsf{d}^\star(A\cup B)+\mathsf{d}^\star(B\cup C)?
$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $d_n(X) = \frac{|X\cap[1,n]|}{n}$. Then: 
$$\begin{eqnarray*}1 + d_n(B) = \frac{n + |B\cap[1,n]|}{n} &=& \frac{|(A\cup B)\cap[1,n]| + |(B\cup C)\cap[1,n]|}{n}\\[0.2cm] &=& d_n(A\cup B)+d_n(B\cup C)\end{eqnarray*} $$
and hence: 
$$\begin{eqnarray*}1 + d^\star(B) = \limsup\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left(1 + d_n(B)\right) &\color{red}{\le}&\limsup\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}{d_n(A\cup B)} + \limsup\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}{d_n(B\cup C)}\\[0.2cm] &=& d^\star(A\cup B) + d^\star(B\cup C). \end{eqnarray*}$$

Comment: (+1) It looks like I as wrong :)